# How to connect an expo app to google firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I am trying to authenticate a user and also organize the users in my database by their uid and then have the data field be by email. The users are successfully being authenticated however nothing appears in my firestore database.

My firestore security rules are in test mode so there should be no issue with permissions. In my action dispatch, I am successfully getting the user from firebase with their uid, access token, and everything else. I believe the error must be some way I am trying to connect to the firestore.

In my app.js file I initialize firebase like this-

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import '@firebase/firestore';

componentDidMount() {
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: 'xxxxxxxx',
      authDomain: 'xxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com',
      databaseURL: 'xxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com',
      projectId: 'xxxxxxxx',
      storageBucket: 'xxxxxxx.appspot.com',
      messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
      appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  }
```

Then this is how I am trying to make the call to put the user into the database-

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
   .then((user) =>
     dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: user });
     const dbRoot = firebase.firestore();
     dbRoot.collection('users').doc(user.user.uid).set({ email });
   });
```

Also at the top of that file, I am importing as follows

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import '@firebase/firestore';
```

Again, these users are being successfully authenticated but they are not appearing in the firestore database.

Comment: Do you see them in `Authentication` part  in Firebase?

Comment: Yes the email accounts are added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a `collection` to the `database` and add `data`.

```js
const dbRoot = firebase.firestore().collection('users');
...
addData() {
  dbRoot.add({
    user: user.user.uid,
    email : email,
    complete: true,
  });
```

OR

```js
const dbRoot = firebase.firestore().collection('users');
...
 const defaultDoc = {
        email: email
      };

async addData() {
  await  dbRoot.doc(user.user.uid).set(defaultDoc);
}
```

Comment: The `dbRoot.collection('users').doc(user.user.uid).set({ email });` in the question fills that same role, but uses the user's UID as the document ID. The latter is a bit more idiomatic as it prevents storing the same UID twice automatically, and makes it easier to find a user by their UID.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I see. I also added the questioner's method to the answer.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen do you recommend against using the users UID as the document ID? I had planned on organizing it that way and storing all of the users info through subcollections

Comment: const dbRoot = firebase.firestore().collection('users'); dbRoot.doc(user.user.uid).set({ email });   I changed it to this and still am experiencing the same problem. Do I need to do it with the callback functions the way you have it?

Comment: @goolius_boozler  As you can see from my answer, I used it in variables. Would you like to try?

Comment: I apologize I am just a little confused. I am trying to add it to the database in my .then() promise. Would I call the function after or put it in as is under my action dispatch? And from what I commented I don't see how it is any different than what I am doing now?

Comment: @goolius_boozler My comment was to Hong, since his answer uses/used `add()`, which generates a new ID every time you call it. I recommend to use the UID as the key as long as you want a single document per UID, which seems to be the case here.

Comment: Ah ok. Do you know what was wrong with my code? I still haven't found the solution.

Comment: @goolius_boozler It is said that it is good to use my first. Try to use it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57583341/my-application-only-uploads-to-database-after-first-account so what you said did work but I think I found the root of the problem, if you have any time in the near future I would really appreciate if you could check out this post

Comment: @goolius_boozler I see. If my answer resolves it, would you like to select the 'V' mark and arrow in my answer to this question, and end the question?