# My application only uploads to database after first account?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

So I am trying to authenticate users to firebase and add them to my users collection and store them by their unique id.

When I go to my signup screen, if I reload the simulator the first account I try to sign up will authenticate but not be added to the database, but any subsequent account I add will authenticate and upload to the database. However, once I reload the application it will restart the process of not uploading the first one.

This is the call I am making-

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then((user) => {
            const dbRoot = firebase.firestore().collection('users');
            dbRoot.doc(user.user.uid).set({ email });
            dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: user });
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
          });
      });
```

Every time the user is successfully created and appears in the authorization section of firebase. And all of them will successfully execute the line dbRoot.doc(user.user.uid).set({ email });.

There is never an error logged to the console and it appears it should be running smoothly, however, the line dbRoot.doc(user.user.uid).set({ email }); will only work after the first try for every time I reload.

I had a .then promise chained to the line in question to check that it executed for the first one and it did every time, I really am not sure what I am doing wrong here and if the problem is with firestore. My security rules are on test mode so there shouldn't be any permission issues.

Comment: It's hard to understand your question. Are you saying your code works every time you run Reload?

Comment: It only works after the first time, after every reload. If I reload my simulator and sign up an account, the first one will not go to the database, but every one after that will. But once I reload it the process repeats itself.

Comment: Where are you running this function? Are you calling this function multiple times?

Comment: Currently, I call the function every time a user presses the sign up button. Right now I have it so when they sign up they don't automatically leave the sign-up screen. So you are able to sign up multiple emails in a row.

Comment: Declare 'dbRoot' before rendering Screen.

Comment: Should I declare it in my LoginForm component and pass it in as a prop to the action creator? I apologize this is my first time ever using firestore

Comment: @goolius_boozler You can declare the `const dbRoot = firebase.firestore().collection('users');` as a global variable outside your function. So you can access it from within the function where you signup users.

Comment: This solved it! Thanks so much.